# Android не видит localhost (Apache)

Tags: android, apache, wifi, localhost

Здравия всем, планшет на андроид не видит localhost, работающий на apache, оба устройства в одной сети. Планшет видит только тогда, когда я подключил оба устройства к хот-споту планшета. Проще говоря, не хочет подключаться к IP от wi-fi сети Извините за столько глупый вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы я мог спокойно через wi-fi подключаться к хосту?

Comment: ип правильный вводишь ?
посмотри в настройках вифи телефона ип адресс. А адрес пингуется с телефона с роутера ?
с телефона проверь через Network utilities.

Comment: Правильный, с настройками также

Comment: Проблема очевидно в настройках apache, раз вы пишите про localhost. Без конфигов apache и точных данных настроек сети можно только гадать.

Comment: спс, буду значит гадать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Центр безопасности Защитника Windows > Брандмауэр и безопасность сети > Общедоступная сеть (нужно выключить) - теперь работает всё